# Javascript - setValue returns #ERROR into a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm really new to Javascript and pretty much copied most of the code and modified it a bit. Sometimes I'm getting an error putted into a cell and sometimes the correct values. Do you know what is the issue?

```
for (p=3; p < 19; p=p+3){

var Value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(9,p);
var outputValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(counter.getValue(),(3 + a));
outputValue.setValue(Value.getValue());
a = a +1;}
```

[image]

I'm adding the whole code as well for reference:

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();
var i;
for (i=2; i < 8; i++) {
  var AddressColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("W1").getColumn();
  //if (ValueCrypto>0)
  var cellFunction1 = '=Value(Replace(IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,AddressColumn).getValue() + '?' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,AddressColumn).getValue() + '"),1,1,))*X1';

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,3).clearContent();  // You can also use range.setFormula("");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,3).setValue(cellFunction1);

    var cellFunction2 = '=Value(Replace(IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,AddressColumn).getValue() + '?' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,AddressColumn).getValue() + '"),1,1,))';
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,8).clearContent();  // You can also use range.setFormula("");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,8).setValue(cellFunction2);
}
  //var cellFunction2 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A4').getValue() + '?' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A5').getValue() + '")';
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').setValue(cellFunction2);


counter2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A12").getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A12").setValue(counter2+1)
if (counter2 = 3) {recordValue();}
}
function recordValue() {

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A12").setValue(0);
var counter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A13");
//console.log(counter)
var dateCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(counter.getValue(),2);
dateCell.setValue(new Date());
//const errorValues = ["#N/A", "#REF", "#ERROR!"];
var a = 0;
for (p=3; p < 19; p=p+3){

var Value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(9,p);
var outputValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(counter.getValue(),(3 + a));
outputValue.setValue(Value.getValue());
a = a +1;
}

var TotalValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("R2");
var outputTotalValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(counter.getValue(),17);
outputTotalValue.setValue(TotalValue.getValue());

var TotalValue2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("R5");
var outputTotalValue2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(counter.getValue(),18);
outputTotalValue2.setValue(TotalValue2.getValue());
      
counter.setValue(counter.getValue() + 1);
if(counter.getValue() > 300){counter.setValue("14");}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Debugger in the Script Error? If you step through your function, you can see what is being returned - seems like your var "Value" may not be returning what you expect?

Comment: Oops, I meant "in the Script Editor" !